# How to handle 304 Not Modified Server Response in Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am building a server which will depend upon HTTP Etag for returning 200 or 304 Not modified response. But I don't know how to handle 304 Not Modified Server Response in Android WebView?

Comment: how r u handling the responses..show me some code.

Comment: @Pratik, Actually webview have some URL pointing to server.

Comment: WebView should take care of 304 ...